# Nsdate always returns null

Tags: ios, nsdate

As i'm getting response from server look like this-(StartTime = "19/02/2016 13:52") and I want to replace this string with this - (StartTime = "19/02/2016 at 01:52 PM")...I want to append AM/PM at the end and I'm using this code...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:userRide.journeyStartTime];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' HH:mm a"];
NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date);
NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

But nsdate is always returning null...
please help...

Comment: `13:52 PM` is redundant, either `13:52` or `1:52 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`19` cannot be a month, so you must have the month/day switched in `@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"`

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up days and months and to get *real* AM/PM you have to set hours to 12 hour format.

```
...
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
...
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"];
...
```

Comment: Problem Solved Thnksss